# How Strapi Services can be used from another node project

Tags: node.js, npm, strapi, yarn-workspaces

I try to use Strapi services from another Node project without fetching endpoint like '/api/rooms/ etc.

Strapi became more powerful since gets TypeScript support. Imagine that you can database call from your directly Next.js or Remix application without using axios or fetch.

to explain that, you can call this query directly from Next.js application with autocompletion without struggled fetch/axios thing. Is that doable?

```js
const entity = await strapi.db.query("api::activity.activity").findOne({
        where: { slug: id },
        populate,
 });
```